# wordpress / php-fpm crashes when uploading images to server

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, wordpress

I have successfully migrated a wordpress server to a new VPC ( Amazon ) but looks like php-fpm can't handle the image uploads. When I upload an image, it does partially and then stalls, or it doesn't even start. After that it hangs.

If I restart php-fpm, the server comes back to life, but the image is ovbiously not uploaded.

So I guess this is a problem of php-fpm not being able to process the file upload. I have logging of php-fpm on but it doesn't throw any errors, only daemon start / stop

```
    [26-Sep-2014 09:17:24] NOTICE: Terminating ...
[26-Sep-2014 09:17:24] NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!
[26-Sep-2014 09:17:24] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 290
[26-Sep-2014 09:17:24] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[26-Sep-2014 09:17:24] NOTICE: systemd monitor interval set to 10000ms
```

Error log in nginx looks like this

```
2014/09/26 09:17:24 [error] 276#0: *1 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 176.32.75.158, server: ec2-54-64-187-3.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com, request: "POST /wp-admin/async-upload.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "ec2-54-64-187-3.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com", referrer: "http://ec2-54-64-187-3.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/wp-admin/media-new.php"
```

As you can see on this error, php-fpm hangs when receiving the call to process the file.

I have raised the logging of php-fpm to error, but the most I get when reproducing the error is

```
[pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (5), consider raising it
```

I have raised the pm.max_children to no avail, problem persist

I can't find any relevant error anywhere else, at this point I am pretty lost

Do someone has experienced this and give me a hint on where the problem would reside ?

Comment: Does this happen everytime when you upload a file or intermittently ?

Comment: all the time, it is a constant malfunction. While I upload a file and I monitor the system with top I see php-fpm working but after like 1 minute there is a timeout, php-fpm stops and I get a "HTTP error" in wordpress.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Cloudflare, or something similar, you could be reaching file upload limit on third party service. If not, I'd check web server upload size. There are 2 variables in php upload:

upload_max_filesize and
post_max_size

Both should be higher than file upload size. Memory might need to match it too, guess depending on script. Finally depending on web server, similar limits are possible:
client_max_body_size in nginx should also be higher than uploaded file.

Comment: I think the solution was already supplied by the requester, I think the limits of the server needs to be increased by increasing `pm.max_children`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).